# String efficiency with small strings

Tags: c++, string

I think i heard somewhere that strings have something called "small string optimization", a way of avoiding allocations. Can I avoid allocations altogether by doing something like this:

```
auto s = "hello" + "world!"s;
```

Instead of:

```
auto s = "hello, world!"s;
```

Comment: Ugh, no. Wherever you heard that, don't visit that place again, on a chance you'll hear something else that's utterly wrong.

Comment: FYI small string optimization is not guaranteed to be used, it is just allowed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik [here](https://youtu.be/xnqTKD8uD64?t=4127)

Comment: Just use a bunch of plus signs, and you can avoid allocations for once and all. This will give you an infinite amount of memory. Of course it's not real as there weren't any allocations. That's why we call it *virtual* memory.... oh, and in case you missed it, I'm being sarcastic.

Comment: @user6419459 And where in that video does it say what you're doing avoids allocations?

Comment: If `"hello, world!"` is big enough to not be covered by SSO then why would combination of two smaller string give you a new string with the same size then be an SSO string?

Comment: Ouch, this is painful. Of course std::string will ultimately do an allocation once it exceeds the thresholds for SSO, whatever that may be in that version of C++, compiler etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, that won't work.  SSO means storing short strings without a pointer inside a string object.  As soon as you concatenate two short strings, it won't fit.  There are string classes that have larger buffers internally, in case you need one that does SSO for say 31 characters.

Comment: Common limit for SSO with string which do not use extra buffer especially for SSO is 15 symbols for 64bit applications. You need only to keep logical end pointer, so buffer begin/end pointers are free for storing characters.